# No se contrae el listado del menú hamburguesa (o colapsado) de Boostrap cuando se hace un click en uno de sus elementos

Tags: bootstrap

No se me ocurre una forma más sintética de describir el problema. Así también me fué en las búsquedas de Google. Lo único que encontré fue esto: https://www.domestika.org/es/forums/5-programacion-cliente/topics/96889-duda-con-collapse-de-bootstrap#
pero no doy con el método 'in' que allí se describe.
Imagino que debe ser un problema solucionado pero no doy pie con bola en los criterios de las búsquedas.

### El problema

Boostrap tiene un elemento en su librería llamado **Navbar**, que no es otra cosa que una barra de navegación que es **responsive design** y en los dispositivos chicos se contrae y muestra un ícono vulgarmente llamado **menú hamburguesa**.
Al hacer click en él se despliega el listado con los ítems disponibles y al hacer click en uno de los mismos somos derivados a una locación del sitio.
El problema es que una vez posicionados el listado desplegado no se contrae y queda tapando parte del destino deseado.
La forma de contraerlo es presionando nuevamente en la hamburguesa, lo que vuelve el proceso muy engorroso. Lo ideal es que se contriga automáticamente.
¿Hay algún método propio de Bootstrap para que el menú se contraiga automáticamente? de no ser así, ¿cómo se solucionaría con Javascript o jquery?

```css
.tamano {
  height: 600px;
}

#seccion1 {
  background-color: #12e952;
}

#seccion2 {
  background-color: #f3d009;
}

#seccion3 {
  background-color: #09a3e0;
}

#seccion4 {
  background-color: #1227e9;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>

</head>

<body id="page_top">

  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page_top">Navbar</a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#page_top">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#seccion1">Sección 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#seccion2">Sección 2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#seccion3">Sección 3</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#seccion4">Sección 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div id="seccion1" class="tamano">
  </div>

  <div id="seccion2" class="tamano">
  </div>

  <div id="seccion3" class="tamano">
  </div>

  <div id="seccion4" class="tamano">
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

  <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
  <!--
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Crear un botón al interno para cerrar el nav

Una forma de hacer que el nav-bar se cierre al clicar un link sin tener que escribir javascript es añadir a la etiqueta `<a>` los atributos `data-bs-toggle="collapse"` y `data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown"` de la siguiente manera:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown">Cerrar</a>
</li>
```

Estos son los mismos atributos que utiliza el botón toggle para cerrar y abrir la nav-bar en tu código:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

**Desgraciadamente esta opción no permite que funcione el enlace, así que solo es útil en el caso de querer un botón para cerrar el nav al interior del mismo.**

---

## Cerrar el nav al clicar en sus enlaces

Para esto es necesario utilizar javascript, en este caso en particular nos valdremos de la versión reducida de jQuery recomendada por Bootstrap.

Esta es la función que efectúa el cierre de la barra nav al clicar en cualquiera de sus enlaces:

```
$('.navbar-nav>li>a').on('click', function(){
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

Y aquí te dejo el código de como aplicar esa función en la página que ofreciste de ejemplo:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body id="page_top">

    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page_top">Navbar</a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#page_top">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#seccion1">Sección 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#seccion2">Sección 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#seccion3">Sección 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#seccion4">Sección 4</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="seccion1" class="tamano">
        Sección 1
    </div>

    <div id="seccion2" class="tamano">
        Sección 2
    </div>

    <div id="seccion3" class="tamano">
        Sección 3
    </div>

    <div id="seccion4" class="tamano">
        Sección 4
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery and Bootstrap js -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!-- Activar popper si se necesita más adelante -->
    <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
    
    <!-- Función jQuery para cerrar el navbar automáticamente -->
    <script>
        $('.navbar-nav>li>a').on('click', function(){
            $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Te hago notar que es importante que importes jQuery antes que Bootstrap de esta manera como se recomienda en el sitio oficial de Bootstrap:

```
<!-- jQuery and Bootstrap js -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: pero al agregarlos el href que tuviera dentro de la misma página dejará de funcionar, también había pensado lo mismo.

Comment: Ya corregí la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias, gracias y gracias.  
 Funciona a la perfección. Me desorientó un poco los enlaces a los cdn. Al ejemplo lo contruí copiando directamente de Bootstrap.  
 Sigo sin entender los atributos data*: ¿funcionan como variables para establecer estados? Ya me pongo a buscar un tutorial en youtube.  
 Suerte.

Comment: Si hablas de los atributos data del primer ejemplo estos son para declarar el elemento con el que quieres interactuar, `#navbarNavDropdown` es el id del elemento.

Comment: yo use esa solucion y funciona a medias, ya que si tenemos un submenu dentro de los items del hamburguesa no muestra los item del submenu ya que al hacer click se esconde.
Probe de usar stopPropagation() sobre el <a> que despliega el submenu pero si bien no se repliega la hamburguesa tampoco muetra los items del submenu. No doy con el camino...

Comment: Es que mi solución no contempla el caso que expones, puedes probar a hacer que tus sub-menus estén ya desplegados al momento de abrir el nav. O asignar una clase a cada elemento que quieres que esconda el navbar al ser clicado y modificar esta linea `$('.navbar-nav>li>a').on('click', function()` por `$('.tuclase').on('click', function()`. Se trata solo de adaptar el código existente a tus necesidades.